# Failure rate of two identical item

Tags: probability, logic, reliability

I have two identical pipelines and the failure rate of a leak in one of them expressed in event/year. The two pipelines are identical and not interconnected. I want to know the failure rate of the situation where I have a leak in both pipelines. Initially I multiplied the frequencies, I asked my boss for help and he said that it is not possible because the unit of measurement cannot be ev^2/y^2. He explained the solution to me, but I don't remember the answer but I'm sure I have to somehow multiply some frequency and some probability.
And the other piece of data I need to use is that the estimated life of the plant is 20 years. 20 years is the observation time of the system and should be a necessary data for calculating the probability.
I need help, thank you very much!! <3

Comment: You have already posted [that question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4889654/446262). Please don't do that.

Comment: I am sorry. But I really want answers, it's my last chance. Thanks for reminding me of this rule.

Comment: Are the two items interconnected, if so how ?

Comment: The two item are two pipeline. They are identical and not interconnected.

Comment: "Estimated life of the plant" means for  both the pipelines taken together, running simultaneously ? Or of a single pipeline ? Give full details of the problem

Comment: I’m voting to close (or even delete) this question, because it is a repost.

Comment: It is the life time of the system. It is therefore considered that both pipelines can running together for 20 years.

Comment: Sorry for this. I just deleted the first post.

Comment: Is the system made up of two identical items? If so, are they in series (if one fails the system fails) or in parallel (if one fails the system keeps going, the second item acting as a backup). If this is the situation I don't see the role of the plant life figure as the reliability of this two item system depends only on the reliability of each item, which you say you know.

Comment: Good choice to delete the first post (since there were no comment on it). I temporarily maintain my vote to close, but for another reason now: the post needs to be edited, for clarification(s!).

Comment: What I need to find is the frequency in events per year (ev/y) with which a leak can occur in both one item and the other. I cannot multiply the two frequencies because the unit of measurement would not be consistent.

Comment: And yes, if one fails the system keeps going.

Comment: All your comments should be edits. Use the edit button just below your post, left to your user name.

Answer (score 1):

If the breakdown rate is $\lambda$ per year then the one year reliability of that item (in its simplest model) is $R=e^{-\lambda}$.
You have a system of two such items in parallel. The one year unreliability of an item is $U=1-R$ and the unreliability of the system is $U^2$. The one year reliability of this system is $1-U^2$. You can calculate this figure to give a number between 0 and 1, let's call it $R_s$.
If $\lambda_s$ is the breakdown rate of the system then $R_s=e^{-\lambda_s}$ and taking logs will give you your system breakdown rate.
You should read up on reliability and the exponential distribution for more examples.